# Django url parsing -pass raw string

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to pass a 'string' argument to a view with a url.
The urls.py goes

```
('^add/(?P<string>\w+)', add ),
```

I'm having problems with strings including punctuation, newlines, spaces and so on.
I think I have to change the \w+  into something else.
Basically the string will be something copied by the user from a text of his choice, and I don't want to change it. I want to accept any character and special character so that the view acts exactly on what the user has copied.

How can I change it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off, there are a lot of characters that aren't allowed in URLs.  Think `?` and spaces for starters.  Django will probably prevent these from being passed to your view no matter what you do.

Second, you want to read up on the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module.  It is what sets the syntax for those URL matches.  `\w` means any upper or lowercase letter, digit, or `_` (basically, identifier characters, except it doesn't disallow a leading digit).

The right way to pass a string to a URL is as a form parameter (i.e. after a `?paramName=` in the URL, and with special characters escaped, such as spaces changed to `+`).

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you can use only strings that can be understood as a proper URLs, it is not good idea to pass any string as url.

I use this regex to allow strings values in my urls:

```
(?P<string>[\w\-]+)
```

This allows to have 'slugs; in your url (like: 'this-is-my_slug')

Comment: BTW, `\w` includes `_`, and `-` is treated as a character rather than a range marker if it's the first thing after the `[` (and optional `^`), so you could write `(?P<string>[-\w]+)`.